# Selenium Java - Can't log in to Oracle APEX application (error: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, oracle-apex

I want to create a testing program using Selenium and test it on an Oracle APEX application. When I try to log in to the application, I get this error message in the console. But I can log in to the application with no problem if I don't use the browser opened by the test program (Selenium).
Have you seen this problem before? If so, could you tell me how you solved it?
[image]

Comment: Can you verify if the cookies are allowed?

Comment: Do you mean the cookies are allowed from the application end? I delete cookies when I run my program just in case, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one instead of the default ChromeDriver:

https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately I use Java, ot Python.